# Point spectrum of a nonlinear operator on finite dimensional space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, nonlinear-optimization

Given a nonlinear operator $T$ mapping $\mathbb R^n$ into itself, are there any known conditions on $T$ ensuring that the number of points in its point spectrum is upper bounded by the dimension $n$?

Comment: How about $n=1$ and the operator $x\mapsto \sin x$?

Comment: Yes, sure. Actually the operator $T$ that i have in mind has many other properties, like positive definitess (i.e. $(x,Tx)>0$ for any $x$). Anyway, I reformulate the question. Thank you for your comment.